# SQL Syntax Error in Join Operation with Subquery in FROM clause

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I've been bashing my head against this one and I'm sure it's a super simple answer. in Excel 2016 VBA I have the below SQL string, but I'm getting a Syntax Error on the Join Operation.

```
SELECT c.code, p.description, p.weight, p.[pack size], p.ppb, p.[CP-UK], p.[CP-EU]
FROM((
    SELECT *
        FROM [Catalogue Info] as c
        LEFT JOIN [Product Information] as p on c.code = p.code
    )
    LEFT JOIN [;database=C:\mypath\db.accdb;PWD=1234].tbl as pl on c.code = pl.product_code
    )
WHERE c.Category = 'VIENNOISERIE'
AND c.Sub_Cat_1 = 'CROISSANTS'
AND c.Sub_Cat_2 = ''
AND p.active = true
ORDER BY c.Page ASC, c.Page_Position ASC;
```

I've tried using the second LEFT JOIN inside the subquery, but I'm struggling to reference it in the SELECT clause.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to use aliases

Comment: @Sami I'm using aliases throughout, where is it that you mean?

Comment: Your from don't have alias

Comment: You need an alias here `) --here
    LEFT JOIN` for example.

Comment: Answer it @Sami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do I think,

```
SELECT j.code, j.description, j.weight, j.[pack size], j.ppb, j.[CP-UK], j.[CP-EU]
FROM(
    SELECT c.code, p.description, p.weight, p.[pack size], p.ppb, p.[CP-UK], p.[CP-EU],
c.Category,c.Sub_Cat_1,c.Sub_Cat_2,p.active,c.Page,c.Page_Position
        FROM [Catalogue Info] as c
        LEFT JOIN [Product Information] as p on c.code = p.code
    )j
    LEFT JOIN [;database=C:\mypath\db.accdb;PWD=1234].tbl as pl on j.code = pl.product_code

WHERE j.Category = 'VIENNOISERIE'
AND j.Sub_Cat_1 = 'CROISSANTS'
AND j.Sub_Cat_2 = ''
AND j.active = true
ORDER BY j.Page ASC, j.Page_Position ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I now get an error 'The specified field j.code could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement'

Comment: instead of the select all in the subquery j select either c.code or p.code

Comment: Do I need to select all other columns in that case?

Comment: Sure thing bro happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the way you are querying external database is a correct syntax

```
    SELECT c.code, p.description, p.weight, p.[pack size], p.ppb, p.[CP-UK], p.[CP-EU]
        FROM [Catalogue Info] as c
        LEFT JOIN [Product Information] as p on c.code = p.code
    LEFT JOIN [;database=C:\mypath\db.accdb;PWD=1234].tbl as pl on c.code = pl.product_code
WHERE c.Category = 'VIENNOISERIE'
AND c.Sub_Cat_1 = 'CROISSANTS'
AND c.Sub_Cat_2 = ''
AND p.active = true
ORDER BY c.Page ASC, c.Page_Position ASC;
```

Also, why are you including external db (`.tbl as pl`) when you are not using it in the `SELECT` statement?

Comment: The syntax for external DB is correct, but using it in the SELECT statement was causing other issues so removed temporarily while I fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
SELECT c.code, p.description, p.weight, p.[pack size], p.ppb, p.[CP-UK], p.[CP-EU]
FROM((
    SELECT *
        FROM [Catalogue Info] as c
        LEFT JOIN [Product Information] as p on c.code = p.code
    ) as t
    LEFT JOIN [;database=C:\mypath\db.accdb;PWD=1234].tbl as pl on t.code = pl.product_code
    ) as t1
WHERE t1.Category = 'VIENNOISERIE'
AND t1.Sub_Cat_1 = 'CROISSANTS'
AND t1.Sub_Cat_2 = ''
AND pactive = true
ORDER BY Page ASC, Page_Position ASC;
```